# CSS3 Animating Bootstrap3 Navbar Height Change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used CSS3 to animate shrinking the size of the bootstrap3 navbar a little bit when the user scrolls down past a certain point.  I setup a bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/IeYZRkb0k2

It's working, but when shrinking, the size jumps a little bit smaller, then animates the rest of the way.  You can see this if you look at the background of the active nav item - a small gap appears between the bottom of the navbar and the bottom of  the 'active' color background.  When it re-grows, the transition is totally smooth & wonderful.

How can I correct this gap?  I tried adding background and height to the transition property but it didn't work.  Also - this is my 1st CSS3 transition animation - so my approach could be entirely wrong.  Is it correct to have the `transition:` defined all 3 places as I have, or can you set it once, and apply it somehow?

Class `smallnav` is added to the default-navbar when `window.scrollTop() > 50`:

```
.smallnav {
  min-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.smallnav .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}
.smallnav .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

transitions:

```
.navbar-default {
  // tried adding height here as well, didn't work
  -webkit-transition: min-height 0.3s ease; 
  -moz-transition: min-height 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: min-height 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: min-height 0.3s ease;
  transition: min-height 0.3s ease;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  // added min-height & background, also didn't work
  -webkit-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease;
  transition: padding-top 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  -webkit-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: padding-top 0.3s ease;
  transition: padding-top 0.3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are only transitioning the `padding-top` value. You need to transition both the `padding-top`/`padding-bottom` values because they are changing; therefore you would change:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    transition: padding-top 0.3s ease;
}
```

to:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    transition: padding-top 0.3s ease, padding-bottom 0.3s ease;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also just use the `padding` shorthand for the same results.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
    transition: padding 0.3s ease;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://www.bootply.com/NoOqh3ov7x)